# uCommerce Order Properties Missing

Tags: c#, sitecore-ucommerce

I have the following method to save order properties on a purchase order:

```
public void SetOrderProperty(string orderPropertyName, string value)
{
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = TransactionLibrary.GetBasket().PurchaseOrder;
    OrderProperty orderProperty = purchaseOrder.OrderProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == orderPropertyName);
    if (orderProperty != null)
    {
        orderProperty.Value = value;
        orderProperty.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        OrderProperty op = new OrderProperty
        {
            Key = orderPropertyName,
            Value = value,
            Order = purchaseOrder
        };
        op.Save();

    }
    purchaseOrder.Save();
    TransactionLibrary.ExecuteBasketPipeline();
}
```

When I save a value using this I can see it appear against the order in the `uCommerce_OrderProperty` table.

However, with some properties, when I try to read them back out they are missing:

```
public string GetOrderProperty(string orderPropertyName)
{
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;

    using (new CacheDisabler())
    {
        purchaseOrder = TransactionLibrary.GetBasket().PurchaseOrder;
    }


    OrderProperty orderProperty = purchaseOrder.OrderProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == orderPropertyName);
    if (orderProperty != null)
    {
        return orderProperty.Value;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

I have also tried this code from the uCommerce site:

```
public string GetOrderProperty(string orderPropertyName)
{
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = SiteContext.Current.OrderContext.GetBasket().PurchaseOrder;
    return purchaseOrder[orderPropertyName];
}
```

If I inspect `purchaseOrder` I can see the `OrderProperties` are missing.  I have 7 properties at any one time but `purchaseOrder` only ever seems to have a max of 5 even though there is 7 in the table.

These are Order Properties and not Order Line Properties. Can anyone give me any pointers as to why I am seeing this behaviour?

**EDIT**

This line does get the value I am looking for:

```
OrderProperty op = OrderProperty.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Order.OrderId == purchaseOrder.OrderId && x.Key == orderPropertyName);
```

Even when this line (called the line after) returns null:

```
OrderProperty orderProperty = purchaseOrder.OrderProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == orderPropertyName);
```

(Both are looking for the same Order Property)

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: two comments: there's no cache on orders, so whatever your cache disabler is doing, get rid of it :-) ! Also you save your purchase order before executing the basket pipeline. Get rid of the save, the basket pipeline will do it for you!

Answer (score 2):

I have a comment, but I'm not allowed because of missing reputation.

Everything seems to be fine regarding your code. Can I persuade you to show the 
uCommerce_OrderProperty table?
- I just want to check that the OrderLineId column is empty for you order properties.

You should be able to set and get it like this:

```
var property = order[orderPropertyName];
order[orderPropertyName] = "VALUE";
```

Regards
Mads

We also recommend that Ucommerce related question is posted at http://eureka.ucommerce.net/, the response time is often faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am seeing the same behaviour with this code,.  some of the properties I can retrieve and some I cannot.  In the uCommerce_OrderProperty table I can see all the properties and all have `Null` in the `OrderLineId` column.  All have the same value in the `OrderId` column and they are all in numerical `OrderPropertyId` order

Comment: Hi Fred, what properties can you not access, and what properties are you able to retrieve?